# React Native notification icon

Tags: react-native

How can I set notification icon in AndroidManifest like
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
My problem is that I need the white icon in the status bar only. And when I put the icon in 'mipmap-xhdpi' it is applied in different places.

Comment: Can you provide the code showing what you've tried so far? It will help others with trying to figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: There is no code) I have icons of app in /android/app/src/main/res/. I have color icons for app and white for statusbar. I put color icons in mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-xxhdpi, mipmap-xxxhdpi, and i put white icon in mipmap-xhdpi. This is how i set icon for notification. But icon from  mipmap-xhdpi used elsewhere. Can I set any setting for set notification icon. I use fcm.

Comment: @АзатГумеров: Did you fix the issue, I m having the same issue